# How to use own layout for navigation drawer activity instead of auto generated layout?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I have a `navigation drawer activity`, that have automatically generated these `activity_student_home2`, `app_bar_student_home`, `content_student_home`, `nav_header_student_home` layout files. I have separately created `activity_student_home` layout.
By default the `activity java class` has the `acitivity_student_home2` layout as `setContentView`. But instead, I want to use the `acitivity_student_home` layout. 
If I try to change the `setContentView` to `acitivity_student_home` then my `navigation drawer view` does not work. How can I use the `acitivity_student_home` layout as `setContentView`?

**activity_student_home layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/app_back"
    tools:context="bd.edu.bubt.regup.StudentHomeActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/showtext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Demo"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_student_home2 layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_student_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_student_home"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_student_home2_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_student_home layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/app_back"
    tools:context="bd.edu.bubt.regup.StudentHomeActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_student_home" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**StudentHomeActivity java class:**

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class StudentHomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    String name, id, dept, intake, sec, mail;

    TextView showtext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_home2);

        showtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showtext); //content of activity_student_home
        showtext.setText("Registration is open"); //does not work. Null pointer exception.

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.menu_bvault) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.menu_account) {

        } else if (id == R.id.menu_pass_change) {

        } else if (id == R.id.menu_logout) {

        } else if (id == R.id.menu_about) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `activity_student_home` does not include your DrawerLayout

This is missing

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_student_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: why is it so important?

Comment: Do you want to change the view dynamically? While the activity is running?

Comment: What I want is my navigation view to work with the activity as well as the contents of activity_student_home.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do what you wish is (if I understand what you are asking for correctly) to use fragments

Inside your app_bar_student_home.xml replace

```
<include layout="@layout/content_student_home" />
```

with something like this

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Then create fragments whose content you wish to show (let's say FragmentA, FragmentB) and set their contentview to the different layouts you wish to show

when you wish to change the content for your activity you can do something like

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, new FragmentA()).commit();
```

there's a lot more to it than this,

for example when you wish to send a click event from the fragment to your activity you have to use getActivity() and cast it to the class of your MainActivity or use an interface (preferable)

you can check out this tutorial which should help you

http://www.androiddocs.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

Comment: No. I don't want to use fragments. I simply want to handle the activity_student_home layout contents. Especially the Textview.

Comment: if I understand what you're trying to do , try changing <include layout="@layout/content_student_home" /> with <include layout="@layout/activity_student_home" /> because as you have it right now activity_student_home is never shown neither it is ever inflated so you can't handle it's textview because it's not there